# Django Populate Dropdown Menu With Choices From Many To Many Database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to populate my dropdown menu with records from the Subject table which is a many to many choices field that is populated with subjects by adding them manually from the admin page. A course can have many subjects such as "business" and "marketing".

Code:

https://dpaste.de/825n

How would I do that with django-select2 or use a form with model select or multiple model select?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Or maybe I could do it with a for loop on the template?

For loops I have tried but no luck:

https://dpaste.de/5MVi

Desired Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdMjE.jpg

Can someone please help me figure it out? I have been stuck for a while now.

Comment: post your forms.py file

Comment: @user6837382 I actually do not have that file.

Comment: you have to create a model form, here is the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: @user6837382 okay and then what happens after that? How do I get it to populate the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

After creating your model form you can use something like this to get a dropdown

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subjects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = [......, subjects]
```

or you can use the other widget, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,depending on your requirement

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}              
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Save">
</div>
</form>
```

Add a create view to create a course something like below

```
class CourseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Course
    form_class = CourseForm
    template_name = 'course_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('/')
```

Comment: Where do I put your code? In models.py? Would I replace YourModel with Subject or Course? What is the ...... for? Why would I need to use a radio button or checkbox for a dropdown menu? Instead of ModelChoiceField would I use modelmultiplechoicefield?

Comment: create a forms.py file and write the code there, Your model will be Course, widgets are optional, and you can use modelmultiple choice field

Comment: updated the answer, add the fields from course in dotted place.

Comment: Still did not get the desired result. Am I missing something? Would I need to do anything in the HTML <select>? Did I do it correctly? -> https://dpaste.de/zARF. When you say fields it should be something like name or slug from the Course model right? Should it be a string?

Comment: a basic form template example also shown in updated answer, if the user wants to create a course, you can create a view and then pass the form as context to use this template

Comment: Tried that and the form is not showing. The only thing that shows is the Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

here hope this helps your missing the .all() on while querying the many to many fields. you're also not going deep enough to the actual name of the many to many fields so you're trying to print the object on your loop.

example view:

```
def tester(request):

    tes = Test.objects.get(id=1)
    testlist = tes.category.all()
    context = {
        'test': testlist,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/t.html', context)
```

example loop:

```
{% for item in test %}
<p>- {{item.cat}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

example  model:

```
class cats(models.Model):
    cat = models.CharField(max_length=10,)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(cats)
```

nested loop example:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
<h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
<ul>
    {% for sub in item.subjects.all %}
    <li><a href="#" id="">{{ sub.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you help me cater it to my code? I tried doing what you suggested and I am not getting the desired result from the for loop. https://dpaste.de/3ezY

Comment: 1. I'm using a function-based view in the example so by adding it to the class-based view it won't even show up. so either uses it as a stand-alone view or make it a class-based view.

Comment: 2. you have a typo for your code its not  testlist = test.category.all() its testlist = test.subjects.all()

Comment: That makes sense. Is it possible to somehow put it in CourseListView? That is where urls.py is pointing -> path('', CourseListView.as_view(), name='list'). I want to be able to display the dropdown on the course_list.html page. I tried putting the function outside of the CourseListView function and it still does not produce the desired result. Fixed the typo also.

Comment: I avoid the built-in ListView for my client's production apps because it feels limiting. that's a controversial opinion though lol. So I'm not the best one to answer that. but you could always in your main for loop try a nested loop with "your_object.subjects.all()" in the template. again I avoid doing that much logic in the template so I'm stretching there.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you help me write the nested for loop?

Comment: added it to my answer above

Comment: Ah nice! I got some results now but is there a way to de-dupe the results to only show unique ones? https://dpaste.de/NHdF and also how would I add it to an html <select> dropdown?

Comment: instead of .all use .filter() with the relevant filters you want to apply from the docs

Comment: update - I will still need the loop you just gave me for displaying each course's subject on the page but for the dropdown where I filter by subject it needs to be de-duped.

Comment: I tried doing this https://dpaste.de/CoW1 but am getting the same result not de-duped

Comment: ok, so we are getting into some bad practices by doing all of this in the template. The better solution is to make the subjects unique but adding the  unique=True in the subjects model.

Comment: The original for loop works perfectly for when I want to list all courses and display their subject. But for the dropdown it would need to be de-duped. So I don't know if doing unique=true would be a good idea or not.

Comment: yes but presumably every subject is unique right? especially since the name is the only item in the model. it won't do you any good to have 3 database objects that are {id:1, name:'history'}{id:2, name:'history'}{id:3, name:'history'} this will be a bid resource drain if it goes into a production like this? I may be missing your point but that is not normal.

Comment: yes okay I will update it to true then. For example in this screenshot, Apple and Django course names could be both considered as Technology subjects. https://imgur.com/a/JVAyUqe

Comment: perfect yes that's the beauty of the many to many fields the same {id:1, name:'history'} can relate to both course objects. but also keep in mind if each corse is only going to have one subject a foreign key relationship is much simpler to work with.

Comment: yea but in this example Django could also be Programming and Apple could also be Business. So how would you suggest next to try and de-dupe this?

Comment: this is all getting hacky for production you need to switch to a custom class-based view and pass the pre-parsed lists through to the template. the hacky solution if the unique = true didn't work (which means the same subj is getting re-looped) is to dump the list thru a js function and de-dupe using js on the front end.

Comment: or you're forced to add a form_class to the listview class which is a whole other can of worms

Comment: wow that sounds complicated I have no idea how to do any of that.

Comment: my advice is to jump back into Django basics really learn function-based views (their easier) and once you know those basics the class-based views and how they work will make more sense. Django's features like ListView and DetailView are great but can be unwieldy if you dont know the fundamentals.If you realy want to path this issue though i would go find a tutorial on django forms and the form_class. Its worth the effort to get right. and dont forget its just python fundamentals

Comment: really do hope this helped